# Why does the cursor jump to a random place unpredictably while I am typing?

Tags: laptop, microsoft-word, keyboard, text-cursor

I'm using Word 2007 on a Lenovo G550 laptop with Windows 7 x32. When I'm typing text looking at keyboard and then raise my sight to the monitor, I see that the at some point cursor has jumped forward to some random place (sometimes outside of the screen), and I'm continuing to type at that location. This is rare, but *very* annoying.

I'm positive I do not touch the cursor control keys or a touchpad.

I've installed Word 2013 and the problem is present there, too.

What can it be? How can I debug this issue?

Comment: Could you be activating Extend Mode with F8 somehow? See https://superuser.com/questions/1634708/what-is-causing-word-and-office-to-start-selecting-text-while-i-type/

Answer (score 2):

You have not given us any information about your laptop or stated if this happens in all programs you are typing in or just Word, so I am going to give you a very generic answer.

Install an external keyboard. If you no longer have the problem, the issue has to do with your laptop's keyboard. This could be a loose connection or it damaged or have a stuck <kbd>fN</kbd> key, etc.

If the problem persists, it could indicate a driver issue or an internal hardware issue.

Comment: I didn't notice it happen in other programs (I would have certainly mentioned it if I did), but 95% of my typing goes on in Word so it's a moot point. What info about my laptop do you deem relevant?

Comment: Just because you don't type in other programs doesn't mean the problem doesn't exits there too. To find out if this a Word issue or a hardware issue you're going to have to try some things. Typing in an different program (whether you use it or not) will help us to know if it is specific to Word. If it happens with all typing, it points more to a hardware or driver issue. Assume nothing; more information is better when asking for help troubleshooting.  Brand and model information allows us to be able to research if there are known issue which might answer your question.

Comment: It's a Lenovo G550 laptop with Windows 7 x32.

Comment: @Violet, Does your laptop have a button to turn off the mouse pad? If so, try that just to make sure you didn't accidentally tap that mouse pad. It's hard to really tell if you actually touch it or not and it will cause the exact behavior you describe.