# What is causing Word and Office to start selecting text while I type?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook

Periodically while typing in Word or Office on a 2019 MacBook Pro, my keystrokes are captured by some sort of search mode that causes them to select text instead. Typically this happens after I type the letter "y", but retyping the same phrase won't make it happen again.

In the example below, while I was typing "synonym", the letter "n" did not print to the screen, but caused the selection of text until the next "n" in the paragraph. Then when I typed the letter "p", the selection expanded to cover the next letter "p".

> [image: Image of selected text]

What is making me enter this mode and causing Word to select text by itself like this? I don't think I'm brushing the touchpad, and I can't enter this mode on purpose by doing that.

Comment: looks like palm rejection issue in the trackpad

Comment: @phuclv It never happens in any other text field I type in -- does Office have some kind of gestures that put it in this searching mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a MacBook Pro with a Touch Bar that's set to always show function keys, it can be easy to brush F8 without noticing that you touched it, particularly when typing the letter 'y'. In Word, F8 activates [extend mode](https://word.tips.net/T000025_Using_Extend_Mode.html). This explains why typing extends your selection, instead of replacing it like would happen after accidental trackpad selection.

You can disable this shortcut by going to `Tools > Customize Keyboard`, selecting the category "All Commands", searching for "ExtendSelection", and clicking Remove for the F8 hotkey.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, it has benefited me a lot !  It's recommended to mark your post to answer, which would help others who has similar issues :).